# Weird Infinite Limit results when dividing functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am getting 0 or 1 for the limit when dividing the two functions but Log of the same constant when taking the limit individually.

```
Limit[f[x],x->Infinity] = Log[C]
```

```
Limit[g[x],x->Infinity] = Log[C]
```

```
Limit[f[x]/g[x], x->Infinity] = 0
Limit[g[x]/f[x], x->Infinity] = 1
```

Is there some reason for this?

The functions are below:

```
f[x_]:= Log[(1 + (a b c + d - c d) x)/(1 + d (x - c x))];
g[x_]:=-(-1 + c) d x Log[-(-1 + c) d x] - (a b c + d - c d) x Log[(a b c + d - c d) x] + (-1 + (-1 + c) d x) Log[1 + d x - c d x] + (1 + (a b c + d - c d) x) Log[1 + (a b c + d - c d) x];
```

More explicitly the limits of the above functions are given by

```
Limit[f[x], x -> Infinity] = Log[1 + (a b c)/(d - c d)]
Limit[g[x], x -> Infinity] = -Log[d - c d] + Log[a b c + d - c d]
```

which are equivalent when you combine the Logs of the second one.

(Also for what its worth, `a>0, d>0, 0<b<1 0<c<1` such that the arguments of the Logs are positive.)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Version "8.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) (December 9, 2010)" yields the same wrong result the OP states. Seems a bug in older versions.

Comment: Interesting, I am on the Student version of Mathematica 12.1.0 for MacOS. I will try updating to 13 as others do not seem to have encountered this bug.

Answer (score 1):

With version 13.0 I get `1` as the limit for both ratios

```
$Version

(* "13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)" *)

$Assumptions = a > 0 && d > 0 && 0 < b < 1 && 0 < c < 1;

f[x_] := Log[(1 + (a b c + d - c d) x)/(1 + d (x - c x))];

g[x_] := -(-1 + c) d x Log[-(-1 + c) d x] - (a b c + d - 
      c d) x Log[(a b c + d - c d) x] + (-1 + (-1 + c) d x) Log[
     1 + d x - c d x] + (1 + (a b c + d - c d) x) Log[
     1 + (a b c + d - c d) x];
```

As you observed, the individual limits are identical.

```
Limit[f[x], x -> Infinity] // FullSimplify

(* Log[1 + (a b c)/(d - c d)] *)

Limit[g[x], x -> Infinity] // FullSimplify

(* Log[1 + (a b c)/(d - c d)] *)
```

Similarly with the limit of the ratios.

```
Limit[f[x]/g[x], x -> Infinity] // FullSimplify

(* 1 *)

Limit[g[x]/f[x], x -> Infinity] // FullSimplify

(* 1 *)
```

Comment: Version "8.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) (December 9, 2010)" yields the same wrong result the OP states. Seems a bug in older versions.

Comment: @Akku14 - I also get the correct results with v12.0.0, 12.1.1, 12.2, and 12.3.1

Comment: @BobHanlon Interesting, I am on the student version 12.1.0 on macOS where I see the bug

Comment: @TTa - I just reran the code again with v12.1.1 and got the correct results. Did you include `$Assumptions = a > 0 && d > 0 && 0 < b < 1 && 0 < c < 1;` ?

Comment: Yes, this looks like something that maybe fixed itself in more recent versions.

Comment: Actually I get 0 when I omit the assumptions. So that part is likely still a problem.